# How do I package and publish a Foundation command line tool in Xcode?

Tags: .net, macos, command-line, xcode4

I'm trying to learn Mac dev so decided to start with a Foundation command line app.

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2.

In .NET you just grab the .exe from the bin folder and either run from it's location, or you can put it in a particular folder in windows and you can run it from anywhere.

Is that how you do it on macs? I know that mac apps are "folders" with the .app extension. But the same's not true for command line tools right?

So, in XCode, what is the final output for command line tools? how do I package it? where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Product --- > Archive